# Client and Server side validation in asp.net MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

We are starting a new ASP.NET 3.5 MVC application. Following are the requirements for validation:

- Both client and server side validation.
- Validation rules in one place.
- Common scenarios like 'Password' & 'Confirm Password' are addressed.

**Options:**

- DataAnnotation (ONLY does server side validation)
- EL 4.1 Validation Application Block (ONLY does server side validation)
- [xVal](http://xval.codeplex.com) Framework
- [Validation Library](http://www.codeplex.com/aspmvcvalidation) framework
- [Validator Toolkit](http://mvcvalidatortoolkit.codeplex.com) Framework
- **OTHERS ?**

xVal and 'Validation Library' both can use DataAnnotation and jQuery validation plugin.

**If a form has a field which is required for 'Create' but not required for 'Update', which of these frameworks can handle this scenario ?**

Please advise which will be the best choice for MVC Client & Server validation ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 4):

I can answer the **others** question :)

[FluentValidation](http://www.codeplex.com/FluentValidation) looks interesting. They provide a fluent syntax like:

```
public class CustomerValidator: AbstractValidator<Customer> {
    public CustomerValidator() {
        RuleFor(customer => customer.Surname).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(customer => customer.Forename).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Missing first name");
    }
}
```

It also have some small integration with ASP.NET MVC, where you can add the result of the validation to the ModelState, as shown below:

```
public ActionResult Save(Customer customer) {
    var validator = new CustomerValidator();
    var results = validator.Validate(customer);
    results.AddToModelState(ModelState, "customer");
}
```